# Attempting to Import CSV with Practical SQL guide

Tags: sql, pgadmin-4

I'm new to SQL and started with the Practical SQL book to learn. I'm at chapter 4 and am trying to import the US Census CSV. I have created the table with the columns as shown here: https://github.com/anthonydb/practical-sql/blob/master/Chapter_04/Chapter_04.sql.

My issue is that when I try to import the CSV pulled from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/anthonydb/practical-sql/master/Chapter_04/us_counties_2010.csv I get the following error:

```
"ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(90)
CONTEXT:  COPY us_counties_2010, line 2, column geo_name: "Autauga County,AL,050,3,6,01,001,1539582278,25775735,54571,22135,+32.5363818,-086.6444901,54571,5370..."
SQL state: 22001"
```

I'm not sure where I am going wrong and would appreciate your guidance. Apologies, if this is an annoyingly simple question, but I am still finding my feet.

Answer (score 0):

Because the error says the value is too long, I looked at what value is meant by this phrase.  The error is referencing geo_name, which is varchar(90) according to the link you referenced from github.  That means the geo_name value must be 90 characters or less to "fit into" that constraint.

It appears that the CSV is trying to load as one long string.  So it's not loading "Autauga County" as the first geo_name, though that's the goal.  Instead it shows this in the last part of the error:

geo_name: "Autauga County,AL,050,3,6,01,001,1539582278,25775735,54571,22135,+32.5363818,-086.6444901,54571,5370..."

It looks like it's trying to load that entire string including commas as the geo_name, so that's longer than 90 chars, so it gives an error.

What are you trying to load it into?

Comment: That's what I thought was happening... I'm working in pgAdmin4. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong, all the manuals I'm working off don't seem to account for this.

I've even tried using the Import tool, as opposed to writing out the code. I specify the comma as the delimiter, and still no luck...

Comment: Sam, I am guessing there should be a "preview pane" type window that shows how the software plans to manage the import, before it actually imports.  That's where I would focus to see if there's anything you can do/change to help it load properly.  After that I'd connect with someone who works on PGAdmin.  I looked it up (I've never used it before) and it's open source... there are probably help forums particular to this program out there.  Best of luck :)